# How to calculate the potential in Hubbard-U correction and when to apply it?

Tags: density-functional-theory, model-hamiltonians, hubbard-model

I have seen that in certain cases Hubbard-U correction is relevant yet I have seen a number of papers that have not used it. So, I want to know if there is any theoretical basis for finding this potential or is it just by using empirical data. Also, what are the situations in which I have to use Hubbard-U potential.

Comment: Highly related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/109/671

Answer (score 9):

I assume you mean including a Hubbard U potential within a Kohn-Sham density functional theory (DFT) calculation. The main reason why you might wish to do this is because you are studying a material for which you expect a significant self-interaction error.

The self-interaction error arises because the Hartree term in the DFT energy functional is the Coulomb interaction of the whole density with itself,

$$E_H = \frac{1}{2}\iiint{ \frac{\rho(\bf r)\rho(\bf r^\prime)}{4\pi\epsilon_0\left\vert {\bf r}-{\bf r^\prime}\right\vert} d^3{\bf r}d^3{\bf r^\prime}}.
$$

This density has contributions from every particle, which means that there is a contribution to the energy associated with a particle interacting with itself - this is unphysical!

The "true" exchange-correlation functional would remove this spurious *self-interaction* and everything would be fine, but the approximate functionals can only remove the self-interaction approximately. If you look at the form of $E_H$ you can see that the self-interaction will be strongest when a particle's density is large, and since the total particle density must integrate to 1 this typically means the particle is strongly localised.

The usual cases where a Hubbard U should be considered are when modelling systems with d- or f-states, especially if they are partially filled. These states should usually be strongly localised, moderately low energy states (shallow core states), but because of the self-interaction their energy is raised spuriously and partially delocalised (because this reduces the self-interaction energy). It is not unusual for the energy of partially filled d- or f-states to be raised enough for them to approach the Fermi level, $\mu$, and hybridise with bonding states. There are other cases where these effects are significant (e.g. the N$_2$ triple-bond); the rule of thumb is that you need to worry about it whenever there are localised regions of high density arising from small particle numbers.

On a lighter note, I wrote a limerick to help people remember the key aspects:

*I once had some d-states I knew

should be found at low E, not near $\mu$

this spurious reaction

to self-interaction

was cured with a small Hubbard U*

For actually *computing* an appropriate Hubbard U, I refer you to the discussion here: [What is the appropriate way of determining a value for the Hubbard-like potential U for LDA+U / GGA+U calculations?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/109/671)

NB using a Hubbard U is computationally efficient, but it is not the only way to solve this. One alternative method is to use a screened exchange functional, which explicitly removes self-interaction at short ranges (where the worst effects arise).

Comment: +10. Nice one Phil!

Comment: If the materials contain some elements with strong correlation effects, can I include that with hybrid functional calculations, such as HSE06?

Comment: @Jack Hybrid functionals can reduce the self-interaction error, although I would encourage you to avoid anything with any *unscreened* Hartree-Fock component as it has a nasty discontinuity at the Fermi-level (screened Hartree-Fock is fine).

I prefer to avoid the term "correlation" here, since it is often misused and defined differently in different fields. Self-interaction errors can occur whenever particles are strongly localised, it does not depend on them being correlated.

Comment: Dear Dr. @PhilHasnip thank you for this nice answer, as always. DFT+U is a method for treating electron over-delocalization due to the self-interaction error in the Hartree energy term. How come adding a +U repulsive potential localize electrons? Doesn't this repulsive +U potential further delocalize electrons by pushing them apart from each other?

Comment: @Sha good question! The easiest picture is probably to consider two degenerate states. The Hubbard U term favours *integer* filling of the states (one full, one empty); in contrast, self-interaction causes LDA (etc) to favour *fractional* filling of the states (both partially filled). The correct physical description is that the energy should be the same however we fill the states! If we add a Hubbard U term with the "right" strength, we can cancel the LDA self-interaction effect and recover the physically correct behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Dr. @PhilHasnip for your answer. Please allow me to ask what you mean by integer filling. Doesn't a Hubbard U term favour the two degenerate "electrons" each to be in a degenerate state and thus a fractional filling instead of integer filling? I thought putting two electrons in the same site will be less probable (due to their mutual repulsion) and adding a Hubbard U potential will "motivate" an electron to prefer being alone in a site, rather than to hop to different sites and meet another electron. Actually, this understanding is exactly the source of my confusion. = (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) = I consulted many resources on the Hubbard Model and DFT+U, but I did not find the connection between the repulsive nature of the Hubbard potential and the localization of electrons. Is there any chance that you consider elaborating more on this please. I can, if you wish, make this a new question on the site.

Comment: @Sha The simple Hubbard form is E = 0.5U.N.(1-N), which is zero for N=0 and N=1, and positive (repulsive) for 0 < N < 1. Thus, the minimum energy state is at N=0 or 1 (integer filling). If you have two states available, that means that the minimum energy is when one state is full (N=1) and one is empty (N=0). In contrast, the LDA self-interaction means its energy is lowest when both states are half-occupied (N=0.5), since that has the lowest squared-density (the Hartree energy).

Comment: @PhilHasnip thank you very much. I think I need much more to understand the seemingly simple Hubbard model and DFT+U.